# How does Ripple decide on the exchange rate between different currencies?

Tags: transactions, ripple, exchange-rate

When A pays in USD but B receives EUR, how exactly does Ripple decide on the EUR/USD exchange rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ripple has an integrated exchange, I guess it simply places market orders in its order book, trying to get the best overall price.

You find the order book in Advanced/Trade, if you want to try manually.

Comment: During a payment, it's actually a bit more complicated than that because the system will consider multiple payment paths. For example, it may consider EUR->BTC->USD, or it may consider EUR->USD on more than one exchange. It's not unusual to find a better rate on a payment than you saw in the order book. (In fact, you can make a payment to *yourself* to exchange currencies, and it's usually better!)